# JNA receive array of structures from C

Tags: jna

I have C code that I am trying to wrap into function calls in Java using JNA.  In this code, I have the following structs declared, where struct B is the return value of aFunction (the function I'm wrapping in the Java library).

```
CORE_EXPORT typedef struct{
   int number;
   char* word;
} A;

CORE_EXPORT typedef struct{
   int numElements;
   A** Astructures;
} B;

CORE_EXPORT B* aFunction(int num);
```

The following is my Java wrapper for this function:

```
public class MyLibrary extends Library{

    B aFunction(int num);

    public static class A extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference {
       public int number;
       public String word;

       public A(Pointer p){
            super(p);
            read();
        }

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
             return Arrays.asList("number","word");
        }
     }

   public static class B extends Structure implements Structure.ByValue {
       public PointerByReference Astructures;
       public int numElements;

       public B(Pointer p){
            super(p);
            read();
        }

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
             return Arrays.asList("numElements","Astructures");
        }
     }
}
```

Based upon my understanding of JNA, I attempt to dereference the PointerByReference in the struct returned by aFunction to the array of A structs in the following way:

```
MyLibrary.B structB = aFunction(1);
PointerByReference ptrRef = structB.Astructures;
Pointer[] pointersToStructs = ptrRef.getValue().getPointerArray(0);

//use each of these pointers to create each A struct
MyLibrary.A[] aStructures = new MyLibrary.A[pointersToStructs.length];
for(int i = 0; i < pointersToStructs.length; i++){
    aStructures[i] = new MyLibrary.A(pointersToStructs[i]);
}
```

Calling the function works fine, but when I try to extract the array of A structs from the struct B returned from aFunction, I get an error stating that "A returns names ([number,word]) which do not match the declared field names ([])".  Is there something I'm doing wrong when I'm dereferencing the PointerByReference in Java?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

After doing more research, I've changed my approach for unpacking the array of structs to the following:

```
MyLibrary.B structB = aFunction(1);
Pointer resultPtr = structB.Astructures.getValue();
MyLibrary.A tempStruct = new MyLibrary.A(resultPtr);
tempStruct.read();
MyLibrary.A[] aStructures = (MyLibrary.A[])tempStruct.toArray(structB.numElements);
```

When the second line executes (structB.Astructures.getValue()), I now get a fatal error detected by the Java Runtime Environment (SIGSEGV). This shows that the problematic frame is C [libc.so.6+0x89a00] memcpy+0xa0.

Answer (score 0):

`number` and `word` must be public fields.  The error message indicates that JNA cannot find appropriate fields corresponding to the names you declared in `getFieldOrder()`; a `Structure`'s fields must be public members if you want them mapped to the equivalent native fields.

**UPDATE**

Your `getFieldOrder()` (in either class) won't compile.

In addition, your native function `aFunction` returns a `struct*`, which means it should most definitely *not* use `Structure.ByValue` as a return type.

You should return a `Pointer` (if you need to dispose of the memory) or simply a return type derived from `Structure` (`Structure.ByReference` is implied for return types).

Generally when using JNA you should use `Pointer` types if you're unfamiliar with pointer and structure dereferencing.  You can make things simpler and more automatic later once you've got a functional mapping.

Refer to the [FAQ](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#when-should-i-use-structurebyreference-structurebyvalue-structure) to see how various pointer and array variations should be mapped.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that when I was writing the question, number and word are declared as public fields in the Struct classes and I was still getting this error. I've updated the question with this modification, thanks!

Comment: That's strange, they compile fine for me.  But okay, thanks, I'll try using Pointers to get the mapping working.

Comment: My mistake, I wasn't aware of the "newer" declaration of `Arrays.asList(T... a)`.